# Explain different components generated for CustomToolWindow in VisualStudio 15 extension template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Whenever we create a CustomToolWindow in visual studio extension template it creates some files by itself , can anyone explain the significance of each file ?
For example if create a CustomToolWindow by the name "Sample" , it creates the following :

```
Sample.cs
SampleCommand.cs
SampleControl.xaml
SamplePackage.vsct
```

Or any documentation on the above .

Thanks,
Dipankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple extension here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/ide/extensions/hello_world
Provide much more information even if it was about the Custom command, but my understanding they would have the same functions:

> The VSCT file is where you can rename your commands, as well as define
>   where they go in the Visual Studio command system. As you explore the
>   VSCT file, you will notice a lot of commented code that explains what
>   each section of code controls.
>
> The CS file is where you can define actions, such as the click
>   handler.

You could also get better understanding these files through this extension sample:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx